# inappbrowser shows white screen after fb share

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I have open a web view of a website in inappbrowser. fb share of website works fine on the desktop and native browser of phone. In the app web view fb share works perfect but after fb share inappbrowser shows white page it does not redirect to the website.

Comment: Please post code and screenshots

Comment: Added 'inappbrowser' tag. Note: what is the meaning of 'fb'?